# switch_root from initramfs is failing

Tags: luks, chroot, initramfs, yocto, schroot

we're trying to implement an initramfs with the intent of:

Open a LUKS partition (using a key saved on TPM)
Mounting the partition RO
Mounting an OverlayFS
switch_root to the new system

The first part of the script seems to work fine. Our problem is in the "switch_root" part which ends in a kernel panic.

Please note that we have the same problem also without the encryption/overlay part. The problem seems strictly related to the switch_root.

We are using Yocto Sumo and the initramfs image is bundled with the kernel.

Please find attached the kernel panic log.

```
    bash-4.4# exec switch_root /newroot /sbin/init
BusyBox v1.27.2 (2020-05-20 09:00:12 UTC) multi-call binary.

Us[  593.127118] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[  593.127118]
age: switch_root [-c [/ d e59v3/.137247] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: init Tainted: G        W       4.14.98+g80655a2d3532 #1
[  593.147478] Hardware name: Engicam i.Core MX8MM module (DT)
onsole] N[E W _5R9O3O.T1 5N3E0W8_] Call trace:
[  593.157367] [<ffff000008089c30>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x3c8
[  593.162798] [<ffff00000808a00c>] show_stack+0x14/0x20
INIT [ARGS]
[  593.167891] [<ffff000008d50040>] dump_stack+0x9c/0xbc
[  593.174075] [<ffff0000080ce5b0>] panic+0x11c/0x28c
[  593.178902] [<ffff0000080d27d8>] complete_and_exit+0x0/0x20
[  593.184495] [<ffff0000080d2840>] do_group_exit+0x38/0xa0
[  593.189828] [<ffff0000080d28b8>] __wake_up_parent+0x0/0x28
[  593.195338] Exception stack(0xffff00000805bec0 to 0xffff00000805c000)
[  593.201800] bec0: 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 0000ffffa819b700
[  593.209644] bee0: 0000000000000020 0000ffffcb90abc8 0000000000010000 0000ffffa81a4a18
[  593.217490] bf00: 000000000000005e fffffffffffffff0 0101010101010101 0000000000000000
[  593.225336] bf20: 0101010101010101 00000000004f2f10 0000ffffa7fe92c8 0000ffffa7fdbde0
[  593.233184] bf40: 0000ffffa7fd7028 0000ffffa800cb68 00000000000005c2 0000000000000008
[  593.241030] bf60: 0000000000000008 0000ffffa8122bb8 0000000000000001 0000ffffa8125000
[  593.248874] bf80: 0000ffffa81265a0 0000ffffa81a3738 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
[  593.256719] bfa0: 0000ffffa812a000 0000ffffcb90ac70 0000ffffa800c7f0 0000ffffcb90ac70
[  593.264564] bfc0: 0000ffffa807946c 0000000060000000 0000000000000001 000000000000005e
[  593.272408] bfe0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[  593.280259] [<ffff000008083ac0>] el0_svc_naked+0x34/0x38
[  593.285620] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[  593.290003] Kernel Offset: disabled
[  593.293520] CPU features: 0x080200c
[  593.297028] Memory Limit: none
[  593.300135] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[  593.300135]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with BusyBox. Maybe there are limitations for the use of `exec`?

Comment: This error message gives very little to work with. Basically all it says is this script, sitch_root, or /shin/init terminated.  I wonder if adding `-c /dev/console` would give more.

Comment: We found the problem. I edited the first post. Thanks.

Comment: Nellorocca that's good you've foud the answer. Please post that as an _answer_ (i.e not in your _question_) so that you can accept it. This shows everyone else it was the solution that worked for you - and therefore is most likely to work for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the solution. Basically, for testing purpose, we were executing our exec switch_root from a /bin/bash opened at the end of the init script. The problem is that switch_root requires to run with PID 1 but, in our setup, that PID was not available since it was occupied by init.

PID 1: /init
PID x: /bin/bash
=> exec switch_root from /bin/bash would assign the PID x to switch_root. That's not an option.
So, for testing environment the solution was to call exec /bin/bash at the end of init and then, as usual, exec swtich_root. For production, we moved exec switch_root at the end of init (of course removing the call to /bin/bash).

Comment: Could you please share in your answer the actual contents of init script that solves your problem? I am also having the same issue, but I do not clearly understand your solution, thanks.

Comment: @krypton-io, I unfortunately don't have access anymore to the source code but this comment explains the problem better: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5033